# listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to run the live-server in my public folder but then it shows this error:

```
C:\Users\Luiz\Desktop\udemy\react-course-projects\indecision-app>live-server public
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: Are you on mac or linux?  Did you use the sudo command?

Comment: I'm in windows, i tried to run this as a root user but didn't work either

Answer (score 10):

you need to change the port.Try

```
live-server public --port=8090
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me. I appreciate the help. Any idea why it would do that?

Comment: @user3727648 It is denying permission for creating the server on port 8080 probably because 8080 is being used by another process.
Check with the netstat command:
netstat -aof | findstr :8080 to see it is in "Listening" status or not.
or you can use the windows util: Start>Run>resmon.exe>Go "Network" tab> "Listening" section

Comment: @user3727648 please vote up if this solution worked for you. Thanks!